# K&R 1.6 Array. Not understanding the code

Tags: c

I start reading the book K&R The C programmming ( 2nd edition). And I got stuck on the 1.6 Array; I just can't seem to figure out what the code does (even tho it says it counts digits, white spaces and others!).  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",nwhite, nother);
}
```

So first it defines Integers, ( c,i,nwhite,nother);
After that it creates an array of 10 digits, ( 0 -9 )
After that it sets nwhite and nother to 0.

the for loops set I to 0, i < 10 means if its lower, add i = i + 1.
ndigit[i] = 0? I dont quite understand it, isnt i already is 0?

while ((c = getchar() != EOF) means What ever the input is and isnt at the end of the file?.
After that part I kinda got lost and I'm not sure what

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

Does at all.

And I don't quite understand why the for (i = 0; i < 10 ; +=i ) is repeated . I do understand English  but some expensive use of words will confuse me. So if you dont mind, please keep it basic for me. I really hope there is someone out there who can help me understanding this code 100%. Because after all, who wants a programmer who cant even understand the code? :)

Comment: That loop is repeated because the first time it zeroes the digit counts, and the second time it prints the counts accumulated by the line `++ndigit[c-'0'];` And what *that* line `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ++ndigit[c-'0'];` does, is to check if the character entered was actually a numeral, if so count its occurrences, by adjusting the ASCII value so that it can correctly index the array.

Comment: I'm still confused. Ehm So what ever you put in the terminal it goes to the if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')  line? And if it is actually a integer or character ( ASCII) it will go to the next line which is ++ndigit[c-'0'] and turn that ASCII int or character into a actually int and add it to the array?:)  I'm quite new to C so sorry if i sound real noobish.

Comment: Your best best is to work through the splendid answer from @thurizas step by step.

Answer (score 7):

Let us step through the code and see what is happening.

```
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
```

In the first first line of code we are declaring[0] (to the compiler) that `c, i, nwhite` and `nother` will be integer variables.  At this point, while we have declared these variables, we have not given them any value.

The next line we are declaring that `ndigit` will be an array of 10 integers, again no initialization is happening so we have no idea of what the value of those ten integers might be.

In the third line we are defining `nwhite` and `nother` to be zero, in other words we are initializing them to some value.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
```

In this loop, we are initializing the variable `i` to be zero, and we will increment it by one ever time through the loop, till the value become ten or larger.  The body of the loop sets each element of the array to zero.  This is a common c-idiom for initializing the elements of an array.

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    }
```

The next block of code does the actual counting.  While the code in K&R is syntactically correct, I prefer enclosing the bode of the while loop with curly-braces, I find it easier to read, but it is a personal thing [1].

The condition of the while loop `((c = getchar()) != EOF)`, can be kind of confusing.  We perform the operation in parenthesis first, which is `c = getchar()` which has the effect of getting the next character and assigning it to the variable c. (remember that in C a character (i.e. variable of type char), is just a small integer so we can assign a character type to an integer type).  The assignment statement has a return value[2], in that it returns the value on the right side of the assignment operator, so the operation in parenthesis returns the value of `getchar()`, which is then compared to `EOF`, and if it doesn't equal `EOF` we enter the body of the while statement.

The first if statement checks to see if the character is a number.  In ASCII, number have the value of 0x30 ('0') through 0x39 ('9'), so we check to see if the character is in that range.  If it is, we increment the appropriate value in the `ndigit` array.  For example, suppose that we have read in the character '5' which has an ASCII value of 0x35.  Because 0x35 is between 0x30 and 0x39 we have a digit.  Performing the subtraction c - '0' is equivalent to 0x35 - 0x30 which equals 0x05.  We then use this as the index into the array, and increment the appropriate value with `++ndigit[c-'0']`.

The next branch of the if-block, check to see if c is a a white space, i.e. the 
expression `c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'` check to see if c is a space or if c is a new-line or if c is a tab.  If c is one of those characters we then 
increment nwhite.

Finally, the else branch is taken if we do not have a digit or white space, and we then increment nother.

```
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

The last bit of code just prints out the results.  Because we want to look at all ten elements of the ndigit array, we need to step through the array again so we use the for loop structure to look at each element of the array.

Hopefully, this clears up some stuff.  Something you may want to try is to modify this code so that it counts the of letters that are appearing in the input as well.  First just try and count letters, with out regard to case, and then see if you can count upper and lower case letters.

notes:
[0] Declaring a variable is just specifying the name and type of the variable, so `int x;` is just a declaration.  We are providing just enough information to the compiler that it can check our usage of x.  A definition is when we assign a value to the variable, so `x=5;` is a definition.  Note that the declaration and definition can be combined into a single line `int x = 5;`.  At the assembly level, a declaration causes storage to be allocated for the variable, but does not set what the storage location contains.

[1] The C grammar says that the curly-braces are not needed for a while block if 
it  consists of a single statement, *i.e.*

```
    while(n > 10)
       c--;
```

and

```
    while(n > 10)
    {
         c--;
    }
```

are equivalent, I just find the second easier to read.  Also, the C grammar 
says that curly braces are not need for the body of an if statement if the body consists of a single statement, so for example

```
    if(n < 10)
         n = n - 10;
```

and

```
    if(n < 10)
    {
        n = n - 10;
    }
```

are equivalent.

Finally, the else if and end all are part of the if statement so the statement

```
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        ++nwhite;
    else
        ++nother;
```

is effectively a single statement, and thus why the curly braces are not needed.

Also, for readability and maintainability I tend to use curly braces with if / else if / else blocks - but again it is a personal think.

[2] The assignment statement has a return value of the left hand side, so a simple expression of `a = 10;` the return value is just ignored.  Having a return value allows us to write something like, `a = b = c = 10` which will have the effect of setting a, b and c to 10.  In addition of having a return value, the assignment operator is right associative, so the above expression would be 
interpreted as `a = (b = (c = 10))`.

-T.

Comment: +1 but one small addition. `getchar` returns an `int` type so that `EOF` (-1) can be distinguished from a 8-bit unsigned char value, so it's a *must* rather than a choice. Note that `'0'` is of type `int`, as revealed when you look at `sizeof '0'`.

Comment: First of all. Thank you so much for going into such details for me. People like you make the world a better and easier to understand place :) I just got a few questions / confirms. So what you said here :  char '5' value 0x35.  0x35 is between 0x30 and 0x39 we have digit.  the subtraction c - '0' is equivalent to 0x35 - 0x30 which equals 0x05. We then use this as the index into the array, and increment the appropriate value with ++ndigit[c-'0']. "                                              Does that mean that 0x05 or 5 will be added into i and i will be added into the array?

Comment: @Recksome_learning_C when you type a '5' (I using single quotes to designate a character) at the keyboard, it is read in as a character (i.e. it has an ASCII value of 0x35).  All characters are represented internally by an ASCII code.   Now, the code for the charaacter zero, i.e. '0', is 0x30; the code for the character one is 0x31 and so on.  In the subtraction, c - '0', we first convert both c and '0' to their numerical value and then perform the subtraction.  the end result is changing the zero character into the number 0 (and so on),  (see part 2 below)

Comment: @Recksome_learning_C.  Think of an array as a series of boxes, each box is marked with a label.  these labels run of 0 to one less then the number of boxes.  Now, square brackets, like ndigit[4], is interpreted as get the value in the fifth box (remember we start counting at 0).  Now a statement like `++ndigit[4]` is equivalent to `ndigit[4] = ndigit[4] + 1`, which can be though of like "get the value in the fifth box, add one to and put it back into the fifth box".  In the example `ndigit` array hold the number of times a digit is see in the input.

Comment: @thurizas Thank you very much for such detailed answer! I spend lots of time to understand "++ndigit[c-'0']" and your answer helped me very much :)

Comment: @thurizas:Your explanation should be a part of the K &R book.. I spent the last 4 hours in trying to understand this code.. esp "++ndigit[c-'0']" bit.. Thanks a lot of the detailed answer. Really helps beginners a lot. :)